# One specific video does not play in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-video, src

I'm not sure if this is even the right place to ask as I'm divided if this is a code problem or a video problem.
I have used on of my templates to design a div that changes the video source based on the width of the screen. It has worked flawlessly hundreds of times, except for today. On the sizes < 767px the video does not appear on IOS devices, regardless of using chrome or safari.
Can you help me figure out why that is?

[HERE](https://sdistribution.impresa.pt/data/content/binaries/1bb/5ca/c585a96a-a05d-47c1-83e0-072654f0a9d5/) you can see it in action:

Thanks in advance